# Force, Square Root and Table Program

Tags: c, sqrt

I'm trying to put together a program that will compute my results in the form of a table. I have a hydraulic lift where it can be shown that a small force (I'm calling it F1) acting over a piston of diameter (D1) can be multiplied into a large force (F2) acting over a piston of diameter (D2), and the lift is operating at 90% efficiency. Finally, D2/D1 is being represented as DR.

Now, I'm trying to use this formula I wrote up "DR = sqrt(F2 / 0.9(F1))" to give results based on me plugging in random numbers for F1 and F2 and put them into a table split into the sections "Input F (measured in lbs.)", "Output F (lbs.)", and the "DR (D2/D1)". However, before I got into dealing with the table, I started having trouble with compiling errors with the first part.

This is what I have now.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int DR;
    int F1, F2;
    int D1, D2;
    int lbs;
    int integer;
    double square_root;

    if(integer<0)
        {
        printf("Cannot find square root of a negative number.");
        scanf("%d", &integer);
        return 0;
        }
        else
        {
        square_root = sqrt (integer);
        printf("\nThe square root of the large force (F2) divided by 90% of the small force (F1)"); 
        }

        F1 = 50;
        F2 = 4000;
        DR = sqrt(F2 / 0.9(F1));

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: This `if(integer<0)` invokes undefined behaviour as `integer` had not been initialised prior to being read.

Comment: scanf("%d", &integer) should come before if(integer < 0) statement

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
DR = sqrt(F2 / 0.9(F1));
```

writes the expression as if it were (almost) math. In C, you must use the `*` operator to multiply things, you cannot suppress it like in math.

It should be:

```
DR = sqrt(F2 / (0.9 * F1));
```

note that since `DR` is an `int`, the result will be truncated to integer.